# Android resources

Tags: android

How to write "A &/or B" in an Android resource? Is the following correct?

```
<string-array name="name">
  <item>A &amp;//or</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the double slash; otherwise that looks correct.  So:

```
<string-array name="name">
  <item>A &amp;/or B</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Thanks. And how to make underline text in the resources and indents?

Comment: @drifter: Outside of asking for clarification, comments shouldn't be used to ask additional questions. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. If you have additional requirements that aren't yet described in the question, edit the question rather than posting a comment. If you have questions beyond what you originally asked, first check whether the question has already been asked, and post a new question if not.